# Cannot insert the value "Null" into column 'xyz'

Tags: c#, sql

I'm having an issue with adding new patients to my SQL database. When I do so, the following error appears, and an SQL Exception is thrown.

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'IntelliMedDB.dbo.PatientRecord'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

The information contained in all of the values that are added as parameters aren't *actually* null. They all have information inside them.

Now, to protect against SQL Injection attacks, all of my queries use parameterized values.

I had an MS Access DB that handled all of this fine (same queries, I've just switched from using `OleDBCommand` to `SqlCommand`. Other than that, nothing's changed).

Here's the "INSERT INTO" statement, followed by a parameterized query, just so you all can see what I've done:

```
INSERT INTO PatientRecord (patientID, firstName, lastName, patientGender, dateOfBirth, residentialAddress, postalAddress, nationalHealthNumber, telephoneNumber, cellphoneNumber) 
                   VALUES (@patientIDNumber, @recepPatFirstName, @recepPatLastName, @recepPatGender,  @recepPatDateOfBirth, @recepPatResidentialAddress, @recepPatPostalAddress, @recepNHINumber, @recepPatTelephone, @recepPatCellularNumber)";
```

(I apologize for the length of the query).

And now, one of the parameterized values:

```
recepPatRecordCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recepPatFirstName", patRecepFirstName);
```

Any help gratefully received.

Thank you!

Comment: Is this procedure for creating a new patient? If so it's unlikely you'd ever want to pass in the `patientID`. Step through your code, what is the value of `patientID` before the insert?

Comment: Can you show the line `recepPatRecordCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patientID",.....` if that exists? Alternatively, can you set `PatientID` to be a primary key index in the table? That would make more sense.

Comment: Your table has a column named ID and this columns is probably the primary key. Check if you have set the IDENTITY = Yes in the column properties

Comment: Hi Steve, I'm running SQL Server 2014. Can you give me some instructions on how to do that, please? @Jason Evans ID is the AutoNumber used by Access to keep track of how many records are in the DB. Patient ID is used for actual patient records (stops the IDs goign all over the place).

Comment: @DGibbs The "patientID" is assigned once the user chooses the "New Patient" option, so that parameter already contains a value. It is necessary so the user can actually display that particular IDs record on screen (I do this by using a Reader).

Comment: Is there an option (i.e. a button) that I can click to drop and recreate a table? SQL Studio is advising I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should edit your question with the definition of the table and the database you are using.

However, the problem is pretty clear.  The `PatientRecord` table has a column called `id` which is declared to be `NOT NULL`.  That means that `NULL` values are not allowed -- and you get the error that you see.  By not setting a value explicitly in the `insert`, the value is set to a default.  With no default, the value is set to `NULL`.

Normally, such columns have a default value or are declared to be `identity` (or auto incrementing).

I think you should probably fix the table so the `NOT NULL` columns have default values.  Or, put in an appropriate value for the `id` column.  For this, you would add `id` to the column list and then a corresponding value in the values list.

Answer (score 2):

Although your `INSERT` statement refers to `patientId`, the error message you are seeing refers to `ID`.

You are seeing this error because no value for `ID` is specified.

Answer (score 0):

```
Open your table in Design
Select your column and go to Column Properties
Under Indentity Specification, set (Is Identity)=Yes and Indentity Increment=1
```

Comment: I'm assuming that id is supposed to be an incrementing value.

Comment: Yes, it is an "AutoNumber" value.